# Import subdomain WordPress into main domain WordPress

Tags: import, export

I have the following setup: two WordPress blogs, one on the main domain, let's call it `example.com` and one on a sub-domain `sub.example.com`. After a few years of running these blogs independently I have to merge the sub-domain into the main domain:

`sub.example.com > example.com`

Each blog's database is over 100MB and the sub-domain `uploads` folder is over ~15GB (lots of high-res images). Both blogs have the same authors and only 2 common categories.

**What's the best (safest) way of doing the merge to ensure that everything runs properly?**

These are the steps I considered:

1. Backup each database;
2. Optimize each database;
3. Backup again;
4. Export XML from `sub.example.com`;
5. Move the contents of `sub.example.com/wp-content/uploads/` to `example.com/wp-content/uploads/` - (and hope there are no files identically named);
6. Import XML into `example.com`;
7. Create `.htaccess` file on `sub.example.com` to 301 redirect all to `example.com`;

The only step I'm not sure is #5, should I move (merge) the `uploads` folders or let the import process handle this as well? I'm thinking that since it's 10 GB worth of images the import process might fail...

If anyone has a better process or if you see a problem with one of the steps from above, let me know, I'll appreciate any help on this matter!

Answer (score 1):

Your logic and the steps you plan on following look good to me. This is more or less exactly how I would handle the issue.

However when you import the XML file from sub.example.com into example.com, you'll want to check the links to the media files within the newly-imported posts. I believe they are still going to be referencing the sub.example.com URL. If that's the case, you will need to run a database updating script or command to update all instances of sub.example.com to example.com.

I use the [Interconnect/IT search and replace script](https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/) or [WP-CLI](http://wp-cli.org/)

So moral of the story - COPY the wp-content/uploads folder over. Don't DELETE the wp-content/uploads folder from sub.example.com until you can confirm all of your URLs are correct.